# YII how to get relations

Tags: yii, criteria

I have two tables Center and Class. the relation between this Centerclass.
relation in Class,

```
'centers' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Center', 'centerclass(cl_id, cent_id)'),
```

and relation in Center,

```
'classes' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Class', 'centerclass(cent_id, cl_id)'),
```

Now if I have center id, how can I get all classes that associate with this Center.

Please give me criteria in Yii for this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the 'with()' method to apply a JOIN relation on the query:

```
$center = Center::model()->with('classes')->findByPk($centerId);
```

And get the classes with a foreach like this:

```
foreach($center->classes as $class){
     echo $classes->cl_id; // Attribute that you like to show.
}
```

Edited:

To use in CGridView:

Controller:

```
$dataProvider =  new CArrayDataProvider('Class');
$dataProvider->setData($center->classes);
```

Add $dataProvider in render to send it to the view.

More info in: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProvider

Or directly in view:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>new CActiveDataProvider('Class', array(
                                                          'data'=>$center->classes)
         ),
    ....
```

More info in:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView

Comment: Hey thanks. but i need to assign all the returned classes into a Class Model List. how to add all returning classes to a array of model class. I'm new to this. never mind.

Comment: The $center->classes its a list of Class Model.
Do you can create a array with 'X' specific attributes of 'Class'?

Comment: nice one, considering the fact, that it was copied from another answer. And it should be not `echo $classes->cl_id;`, but `echo $class->cl_id;`, and regarding your question in comment you can just assign `$center->classes` directly to `to an array of model class`

Comment: @LazKarimov i'm sorry, but i not copied you answer.. i've put it 7 mins later than you, the time i took to write it.

Comment: when I directly pass '$center->classes' into a view to render , I get following error.  Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\zii\widgets\CBaseListView.php on line 107

Comment: @Daniel Vaquero Thanks that did my work. but I changed CArrayDataProvider to CActiveDataProvider. because when I put CArrayDataProvider, it gave me an error 'Property Class.id not defined'. 
and still there is another problem now. let me explain. Total number of classes are 11. center1 is associated with 5 classes. but when we list the above result, the pagination shows that 1-5 of 11 that it shows exactly five results but pagination tells that i has 11 element. I don't i explained well. if you get it please help me. again thank you for your help.

Comment: Try putting CActiveDataProvider('Class', array('pagination'=>false) );

Answer (score 0):

```
$center = Center::model()->with('classes')->findByPk($centerId);
foreach($center->classes as $class){
...
}
```